# How to enable a product in a subscription of RHEL 7.5?

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, powerpc

How can I install a product displayed by the output of `subscription-manager list --consumed`?

Right now, I have only one product installed on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5.

```
$ sudo subscription-manager list --installed
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power, little endian
Product ID:     279
Version:        7.5
Arch:           ppc64le
Status:         Subscribed
Status Details:
Starts:         10/07/2018
Ends:           10/07/2019
```

The `subscription-manager list --consumed` command shows other products, one of which I would like to install.

```
$ sudo subscription-manager list --consumed
+-------------------------------------------+
   Consumed Subscriptions
+-------------------------------------------+
Subscription Name:   Red Hat OpenShift, Standard Support (10 Cores, NFR, Partner
                     Only)
Provides:            Red Hat OpenShift Container Platform
                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power, little endian -
                     Extended Update Support
...snip...
                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power 9
...snip...
```

Since "Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power 9" is in the list, I already have a license to install it, correct?  Is there any way to enable it by, say, subscription-manager, so that the corresponding repos are added to `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` and the packages can be installed with yum?  Or, do I have to obtain a license key of the product by any other means?

My system is RHEL 7.5 POWER 9 ppc64le, but I suppose this is a platform-independent question.

Answer (score 2):

Not having access to RHEL on POWER, nor your specific partner subscription, I'll just answer this in the general case.

First, you purchase or obtain a RHEL *subscription* from Red Hat. Each of these has a different name. Yours is named "Red Hat OpenShift, Standard Support (10 Cores, NFR, Partner Only)".

Each *subscription* contains one or more *products*, and these are listed in the `subscription-manager list` command. For example, among others you have "Red Hat OpenShift Container Platform" and "Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power, little endian - Extended Update Support".

Each *product* grants access to one or more *repos*. And these repos actually contain the software. You can list all the available repos with `subscription-manager repos` and `--list-enabled` or `--list-disabled`.

By way of example, one product in my subscription is `Red Hat Ansible Engine`. It adds the following repos and makes them available to be enabled:

```
Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2 Source RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.6-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.6 Source RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.6/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.6-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.6 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.6/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.7-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.7 Source RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.7/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.5-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.5 Source RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.5/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.7-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.7 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.7/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.4 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.4/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.5-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.5 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.5/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2 Debug RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.7-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.7 Debug RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.7/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.4 Source RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.4/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.4-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.4 Debug RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.4/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.5-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.5 Debug RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.5/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-ansible-2.6-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.6 Debug RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/ansible/2.6/debug
Enabled:   0
```

---

I think one point of your confusion is that you are using a narrow terminal and `subscription-manager` continues a long title onto the next line. Thus where you are seeing "Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power 9" this is most likely the end of a much longer name that wrapped from the previous line. Maximize your terminal window and try again.

For example, compare these outputs from a narrow versus wide terminal:

```
Provides:            Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Availability - Update
                     Services for SAP Solutions
```

versus

```
Provides:            Red Hat Enterprise Linux High Availability - Update Services for SAP Solutions
```

Comment: Regarding the first half, thanks for the clarification about the relationship between a subscription, products, and repos. Looks like my understanding was correct.

Regarding the second half, yes, my terminal was not wide, but even after maximizing it, I found the product name was still "Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Power 9".  So, my question is still "how to install it...?", or in other words, "how to add the repos of the product to redhat.repo...?"

Comment: @Rei They will already be there. Unfortunately I know of no easy way to determine which repos correspond to which product. I would certainly like to see one.